# parse check doesn't work

Tags: java, string, date

hi guys i am using this method to check if a string can be converted to a date or not but it seems that it's not working, this is the code i wrote, the user inputs a date in this format dd/MM/YYYY then this is what happens for checking it

```
...
String date  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Insert Date:");
    if (date ==null) { return;}
    while (!(isValidDate(date))) {          
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect Date");
        date = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Insert Date:");
        if (date ==null) { return;} }
    String[] parts = date.split("/");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    ...
```

and this is the method for check the date

```
public boolean isValidDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    if (dateString.length() != "ddMMYYYY".length()) {
        return false; }
    try {
        df.parse(dateString);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
```

this seems not to work cause it always goes into the while block whatever i insert in the input, what is the problem with this code ?

EDIT

fixed the error on the condition

```
if (dateString.length() != "ddMMYYYY".length())
```

now i got another problem it accepts values like 54/12/2030 which obvioiusly are not a date format

Comment: maybe `"dd/MM/YYYY".length()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition seems to be wrong... This is how it should be.

```
 if (dateString.length() != "dd/MM/YYYY".length())    return false;
```

if input date is 22/07/1986 obviously it's length will be more than length of ddMMYYYY because of missing slashes.

`df.setLenient(false);` Will ensure that it won't roll over for invalid dates. Just put thiss line after you created df object.

Comment: +1, but actually you would not need that condition at all, right?

Comment: thanks now works for a part but now it accepts values like 54/20/2013

Comment: @tobias_k of course I wouldn't write that condition either, I'm merely pointing out issue.

Comment: @TheBigBoss use setLenient as I updated my answer, to fix your issue of taking invalid dates.

Comment: i just inserted that cmd after df object creation but it doesn't work still taking invalid dates

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good reason for why you should use a static final define rather than repeating the same string throughout your code. You are comparing against one string and parsing against another, so the two are never going to match.

I also don't understand why you would go through SimpleDateFormat to parse a Date (which has things like year, month etc available as method calls) and then throw that away in order to parse the String again by hand.

Just rename `isValidDate` to `parseDate`, have it return a Date object or null if not valid, and have the while loop continue so long as the Date returned is null.

Comment: because my class constructor takes ints respectively for create a new Date with those ints as fields, in my first attemp my constructor took a Date but taking a date directly cause me to store a wrong date caused by the deprecation because i can't sub 1900 to the year and 1 to the month

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you want your date to be separated by `/` in most places, but you check if the string has the same length as `"ddMMYYYY"`. You should probably change your `isValidDate()` method to include the slashes (and a trailing close-brace):

```
public boolean isValidDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    if (dateString.length() != "dd/MM/YYYY".length()) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        df.parse(dateString);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed that error but now it takes values like 54/12/3013 as good dates

Comment: Technically that is a valid date in lenient mode. You may want to try `df.setLenient(false)`.

Comment: inserted that but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

for last problem  i had referring to values like 54/77/4444 i changed the YYYY to yyyy and it worked